# Makeinfo package not found in 12.04

Tags: package-management, compiling, make

Please can anybody give me an answer for this? I have already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install makeinfo textinfo texi2html
```

But, I still get the error:

```
Unable to find the pacakge.
```

Comment: cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401079/makeinfo-package-missing-in-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [this is a crosspost already answered elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401079/makeinfo-package-missing-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 13):

If you would have executed `makeinfo` directly, it would have suggested you the right package name:

```
$ makeinfo
The program 'makeinfo' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install texinfo
```

After installing the `apt-file` package, you could also locate it with `apt-file`:

```
$ apt-file search makeinfo
...
texinfo: /usr/bin/makeinfo
...
```

[Searching for "makeinfo" on packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=makeinfo) would give the same information as apt-file.

Answer (score 6):

You need to type "texinfo" not "textinfo".

Answer (score 3):

There is two way to install texinfo, Download (http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/) and build using configure option, but you might get Exception like, Makefile:18283: *** missing separator stop

and the easiest way is by running the below command in your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install texinfo
```

Answer (score -2):

Open a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install makeinfo texinfo texi2html
```

Note that `makeinfo` has been removed.

Comment: Can you add some detail, like how and why this should work?